# Get intersection points between multipolygon and multiline

Tags: postgis, intersection

I am trying to get the intersection points between the boundary of a city (stored in the database as a `MultiPolygon`) and the OSM roads (stored as `Multiline string`).

I am using `ST_intersect(city.geom, roads.geom)` as a `where` clause but I am not getting any results.

If I open the tables in `QGis` I see that there are intersections. Do I need to transform any of the `geom` ?

Comment: There is no ST_intersect. Did you mean ST_Intersection http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html? Or http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html which is obviously wrong function if you read the documentation.

Comment: Can you post a SQL query ?

Comment: select st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) geom from a join b on st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) --- this should be syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to work with MultiPolygon and MultiLineString ?
If not, first you need to check if you multi geometries really contains multi geometries - i.e if spatially disconnected entities are present. I often work with OSM data and I also get multi geometries whenever I import QGIS-created shapefiles in PostGIS.

Run the following query for each of your tables :

```
SELECT count(
    CASE WHEN ST_NumGeometries(t.geom) > 1
    THEN 1 END
    ) AS multi,
    count(t.geom) AS total
FROM the_table t; --Replace the_table by the table you want to test
```

If the first column returns 0, it means you don't actually have multi geometries, they're only stored as such. Then you can easily convert your geometry column to simple geometry using :

```
ALTER TABLE multipolygon_table
    ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Polygon, 4326) --Replace 4326 by the SRID you are using
    USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1);

ALTER TABLE multilinestring_table
    ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(LineString, 4326) 
    USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1);
```

If your data really contains multi geometries (first column of the first query returns a value > 0), you should dump them into simple geometries (Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719941/postgis-convert-multipolygon-to-single-polygon)

To get the intersection between the boundary of your city and the roads, I suggest you first create a CTE (kind of a temporary table created with WITH) containing the border of your polygons as line(s) and then run the ST_Intersection function combined with ST_Intersects (to work only on roads that actually intersect the boundaries) to obtain points :

```
WITH boundary AS (
    SELECT id, ST_ExteriorRing(geom) as geom
    FROM city_table
    )
SELECT r.id as road_id, ST_Intersection(r.geom, b.geom) as geom
FROM road_table r, boundary b
WHERE ST_Intersects(r.geom, b.geom);
```

This is suppose to work because the intersection between two lines returns a point.
Be aware that ST_ExteriorRing only works with simple polygons so you need to convert them in the first time.

Forgive me if some explanations are obvious but I tried to be as explicit as possible.